# How do I associate an uploaded file to an Organic Group?

Tags: 7, organic-groups, files, media

In D6 we have

```
mysql> describe files;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| fid       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uid       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| filename  | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| filepath  | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| filemime  | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| filesize  | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| status    | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| timestamp | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In D7 we have

```
mysql> describe file_managed;
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default   | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
| fid       | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL      | auto_increment |
| uid       | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | 0         |                |
| filename  | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |           |                |
| uri       | varchar(255)        | NO   | UNI |           |                |
| filemime  | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |           |                |
| filesize  | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0         |                |
| status    | tinyint(4)          | NO   | MUL | 0         |                |
| timestamp | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | 0         |                |
| type      | varchar(50)         | NO   | MUL | undefined |                |
| uuid      | char(36)            | NO   | MUL |           |                |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
```

Is there a module (or more automated drupal-y way) of associating an uploaded file with an Organic Group [[OG]](https://www.drupal.org/project/og)? I need a way to let *only group members have access to these uploaded files*.

**That is, how can I have a field called `og_groups` and have drupal react to it automatically?**

**Side note**: We're migrating this project from D6 ([Commons](https://www.drupal.org/project/commons) 2.x) to a plain D7 install base with OG that will decouple the application from Commons 2.x. So a D7 approach would be most appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [How to restrict access to private files to members of an organic group?][1]


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90357/how-to-restrict-access-to-private-files-to-members-of-an-organic-group

Comment: Thank you @fullerja. I'm linking to this answer http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/99795/5966 but leaving the question open in case anyone has further input.